# Persist virtual keyboard on mobile devices in Blazor app

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a chat app built in Blazor that is responsive to mobile devices. The chat interface has a `textarea` element and a send `button`. The `textarea` autofocuses, which opens the virtual keyboard, however, when the user touches the send `button`, the keyboard drops because the `textarea` loses focus. I have some code to refocus the `textarea`, but the keyboard still drops momentarily before reopening. How do I get it to persist?

I tried using the `@ref` functionality in Blazor to refocus the `textarea` in the `@onclick` method:

#### HTML

```html
    <div class="message-input-block">
        <textarea class="message-input" @onkeydown="HandleKeyPress" type="text" placeholder="Send a message" @bind-value="messageInput" @bind-value:event="oninput" autofocus @ref="textInput" />
        <button class="send-button" @onclick="Send" disabled="@(Chat.IsConnected == false)"></button>
    </div>
```

#### `@code` section containing the `Send` function

```cs
    private async Task Send()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(messageInput))
            return;

        await textInput.FocusAsync();
        switch (selectedChat)
        {
            case "team":
                await Chat.SendTeamMessage(messageInput);
                break;

            case "host":
                await Chat.SendHostMessage(messageInput);
                break;

            default:
                await Chat.Send(messageInput);
                break;
        }

        messageInput = string.Empty;
    }
```

This still results in the toggling behavior where the keyboard drops, then immediately reappears as the focus changes. I would prefer the keyboard to persist when the user clicks the button.

EDIT:
I've also tried some javascript solutions to no avail.

```js
window.keepKeyboardUp = function () {
    var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
    textareas.forEach(function (textarea) {
        textarea.addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
};


window.keepFocusOnElement = function (elementId) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (element) {
            element.focus();
        }
    }, 100);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be to make the containing `div` `contenteditable` but ignore any key presses inside that div so the user can't type in it.

```html
<div class="message-input-block" contenteditable="true" onkeydown="if(event.target==this)return false">
 <textarea class="message-input" @onkeydown="HandleKeyPress" type="text" placeholder="Send a message" @bind-value="messageInput" @bind-value:event="oninput" autofocus @ref="textInput" />
 <button class="send-button" @onclick="Send" disabled="@(Chat.IsConnected == false)"></button>
</div>
```

You might want to put the JS code in a script rather than inline like that, but I'll leave that to you as this demonstrates a technique that answers the question.

How does it work? Well, the keyboard is shown on a mobile device when an element that is editable (in this case `contenteditable`) has focus (or more crucially `focus-within`) so even when the button has focus the keyboard is shown because the containing div also has focus and it is `contenteditable`